Mouse Navigation Issue in Jupyter Notebooks within VSCode
I'm encountering an issue with Jupyter Notebooks in VSCode where, at random intervals, certain cells become unresponsive to mouse navigation. Clicking within the cell places the cursor at the end of the line instead of where clicked. However, I'm still able to navigate within the cell using the keyboard.
The problem resolves temporarily when I cut and paste the full text within the affected cell. Can anyone provide assistance or suggest a solution for this problem? It could be
I just updated my fedora KDE to 40 and the VSCode to 1.88.1 along with it this week.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
